# Using @Autowired in Spring 3

Tags: java, spring

I have a JPA application that uses Spring 3.  I am attempting to use @PostConstuct to iniaialise a database with specific Facility codes.  When I persist a code within the Class that has the @PostConstuct method - it works.  When I call a second class to persist the codes, it fails.  Is this something to do with the way I am using the @Autowired annotation?

This is a segment of the Preloader class:

```
public class Preloader {
   @Autowired
   private FacilityService service;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
      loadCodeSet();
   }

   private void loadCodeSet() {
      // This works
      Facility created = new Facility();
      created.setCode("Uni");
      created.setDescription("University");

      Facility returned = service.create(created);

      // This fails
      CodeSetLoader cl = new CodeSetLoader();
      l.load();
    }
```

This is a segment of the loading class:

```
public class CodeSetLoader {

    @Autowired
        private FacilityService facilityService;

    public void load() {
        loadFacilities();
    }

    private void loadFacilities() {
        Facility test = new Facility();
        test.setCode("UNI");
        test.setDescription("University");

        Facility returned = facilityService.create(test);
    }
```

The exception includes:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at util.CodeSetLoader.loadFacilities(CodeSetLoader.java:42)
    at util.CodeSetLoader.load(CodeSetLoader.java:24)
    at util.Preloader.loadCodeSet(Preloader.java:68)
    at util.Preloader.init(Preloader.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:130)
    ... 22 more
```

Hoping somebody may be able to assist with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Autowired`, `@PostConstruct`, and friends only work on managed beans, not objects you call `new` on. If Spring doesn't know about the bean, it can't autowire it.

Comment: Thank you for this - how should I implement this then?  Would I be better to use JPA without Spring or would it be better to create manages beans?

Comment: I am not sure how it would work - but maybe my PreLoader class should be a managed bean?

Comment: @bugy It depends entirely on what you're trying to do. Probably the `CodeSetLoader` class should have a Spring bean that you inject into `Preloader` (and `Preloader` needs to be a bean, too).

Comment: This seems to work if I inject both the Preloader bean and the CodeSetLoader bean then @Autowired works in both cases.  Thank you for this - I am starting to understand how it all works :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to `@Autowired` CodeSetLoader in your Preloader:

```
public class Preloader {
   @Autowired
   private FacilityService service;
   @Autowired
   CodeSetLoader codeSetLoader;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
      loadCodeSet();
   }

   private void loadCodeSet() {
      // This works
      Facility created = new Facility();
      created.setCode("Uni");
      created.setDescription("University");

      Facility returned = service.create(created);

      codeSetLoader.load();
    }
}
```

Comment: does this mean that Autowiring the CodeSetLoader at this point would allow @Autowired to function correctly in the CodeSetLoader class or does Spring need to be told about the CodeLoader class?

Comment: @bugy the once the component is autowired by spring, autowiring will work correctly in it. How are you defining these components?

Answer (score 2):

Autowired is called only for object created by Spring.

If possible, you should autowire CodeSetLoader instead of calling `new` :

```
public class Preloader {
   @Autowired
   private FacilityService service;

   @Autowired
   CodeSetLoader codeSetLoader;
```

Answer (score 1):

You constructed `CodeSetLoader` yourself rather than letting Spring do so. As a result, `facilityService` never got autowired.

You need to let Spring manage both.

Comment: Ok, I am starting to understand this.  I am now telling Spring about the bean in context.xml and using @Autowired in both the PreLoader class and the CodeSetLoader class